# Wordpress - Breadcrumbs with custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to show breadcrumbs under the **schema.org** convention, but I couldn't find any solution for now.

If I check my code with [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) I get two errors: one for the second element in the breadcrumb ("ID is required") and the other one for the third element ("name or item.name are required").

I guess the issue is with how I get the taxonomy term and the post title, but I don't know how I could do it any other way:

```
// For the taxonomy
<?php echo get_the_term_list($post-> ID, 'genres') ?>

// For the post title
<?php the_title();?>
```

Here is the entire code:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <ol itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">

    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
      <a itemprop="item" href="https://mybooks.com">
        <span itemprop="name">My Books</span>
      </a>
      <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
    </li>
   
    ›

    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
      <a itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemprop="item" 
        itemid="<?php echo get_the_term_list($post-> ID, 'genres') ?>" 
        href="<?php echo get_the_term_list($post-> ID, 'genres') ?>">
        <span itemprop="name"><?php echo get_the_term_list($post-> ID, 'genres') ?></span>
      </a>
      <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
    </li>

    ›

    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
      <span itemprop="name"><?php the_title();?></span>
      <meta itemprop="position" content="3" />
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Any suggestion to solve these issues?

Thanks!

Comment: In case this can help someone, I found a plugin that does exactly what I was looking for. It shows the taxonomy corresponding to the CPT in the breadcrumb.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/

Answer (score 0):

---

### Knowledge

---

As per the Google Developers website:

> To be eligible after January 29, 2021, you need to replace data-vocabulary.org markup with schema.org markup.

- Source @ https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb

If we take a look at the [https://schema.org/](https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList) website. We can get a good understanding on how to structure our datas.

The Microdata example shared by schema.org is the following one.

```
<ol itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses">
    <span itemprop="name">Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
  </li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses/real">
    <span itemprop="name">Real Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
  </li>
</ol>
```

- Source @ https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList

Taking that into account we can adapt your code to match the schema.org reference example.

You're adding `itemid`, `itemscope` and `itemtype` to the second  tag item. Which is probably where the problem is coming from. If we test your structure without those we pass with flying colors.

Keep in min that if you're on localhost, `item` will return an error as `http://localhost:8080/` will be considered as an error.

Here is your result:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <ol itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
      <a itemprop="item" href="https://mybooks.com">
        <span itemprop="name">My Books</span>
      </a>
      <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
      <a itemprop="item" href="https://mybooks.com/genre">
        <span itemprop="name">Genre</span>
      </a>
      <meta itemprop="position" content="2">
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
      <a itemprop="item" href="https://mybooks.com/genre/my-awesome-great-title">
        <span itemprop="name">My awesome great title</span>
      </a>
      <meta itemprop="position" content="3">
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

---

### Sharing my 2-cents

---

Using the user current url and building a breadcrumb on top of it would simplify your life.

I made a vanilla `.js` script a while back to easily generate a breadcrumb. I've edited it to match your structure. It should be a plug and play.

You won't have to deal with the hassle of specifying each and every pages.

Just add the following tag...

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <ol id="bread" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList"></ol>
</div>
```

...and scripts to your website and you should be good to go. Modify it and have fun!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pathname = location.pathname;
if (((bread = []), pathname.endsWith("/"))) var crumbs = pathname.split("/").slice(1, -1);
else crumbs = pathname.split("/").slice(1);
for (crumb = 0; crumb < crumbs.length; crumb++) {
    var url = location.href.split(crumbs[crumb])[0];
    if (crumbs[crumb].length > 35) var short = crumbs[crumb].replace(/-/g, " ").substring(0, 35) + "[...]";
    else short = crumbs[crumb].replace(/-/g, " ");
    bread.push('<li style="display:inline;padding:0 5px;" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a itemprop="item" href="' + url + crumbs[crumb] + '"><span itemprop="name">' + short + '</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="' + (+crumb+1) + '"></li>'); // ... you can remove the style from the <li> tag if you're adding a custom one via css or else.
}
(document.getElementById("bread").innerHTML = bread.join(">")), // ... if you're adding the separator via css or else, just remove the ">" symbol.
(document.getElementById("bread").lastChild.style.pointerEvents = "none"),
(document.getElementById("bread").lastChild.firstElementChild.style.textDecoration = "none"),
(document.getElementById("bread").lastChild.firstElementChild.style.color = "inherit");
</script>
```

The comments should guide you to easily customize it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I would like to use 'get_the_term_list($post-> ID)' or something similar to create my own structure for the breadcrumbs.